# Stateless Controller Or Persistable ViewModel?

Tags: android, architecture, google-api, viewmodel

Tldr: Am I right to think that having a stateless Controller, that only observes its models individual values is better than having a persistent ViewModel that observes its entire model?

Looking at the new architecture package released by Google at IO, as far as I see they are using a persistable ViewModel along with a data wrapping that observes for all changes.

I'm doing it with a stateless Controller that takes a data model then breaks it down and observes individual values instead of the entire object every time.

Keeping it tied to config changes and lifecycles, if needed. Is done by creating base Controller on any base class(activity or fragment) that uses them.

If code or further clarification is needed please just ask I'll be happy to accommodate. Sorry if this is the wrong SE site for this type of question.

Jon.

Comment: While I can't guarantee that I have any useful guidance for this question, I'd be curious to see the code that creates the stateless ViewModel objects if you still want to discuss this.

Comment: I have sort of pushed this out of my mind lol. I spent a fair amount of time figuring it out, and they introduce almost exactly the opposite of what I've done. Frustrating to say the least. However I will absolutely take the time and put together a simple gist list later on tonight or tomorrow, would more than appreciate any and all input. Even if that input is, 'it's all wrong' etc.. Either way, thank you.

Comment: Yeah. Whenever's convenient. No rush. It's an interesting discussion. I'll check back later.

Comment: @albert braun - https://gist.github.com/1b08d50e29d6219b53fd98bd59920563

Thats a mostly sanitized and small example. The link in its description is a project I contributed to, and has everything I'm doing in the gist+.

Sorry if it's not all very clear, I'm still novice level. Let me know any thoughts you may have.

Comment: You'll see it does all work, not just for fragments and activities but also viewholders. Flattening them to a common interface/s. Not sure if that is something I should be striving for though. All that aside I have come to the conclusion, that Googles solution goes much further than mine does(obviously), they answer several questions at once while I only answer one. And it may be the only logical road to take. Instead of trying to marry them together.

Comment: Just a side note, I name them Controllers but I mean ViewModel of course. The name change happened after io...

Comment: Thank you for the code. I realize now that your view model class (aka 'controller') is your own custom class. I'd misunderstood earlier. I had thought you were instantiating the new android ViewModel class. So, I guess my earlier question becomes something more like: how does a Controller object instance get into the MainActivity? It's injected? Just trying to understand. Again, thanks.

Comment: This is why I started calling it a controller, probably should have followed my own lead with the question. Sorry. It's old, but I'll edit it anyway. And to answer your question: Yes, it is injected using dagger(I believe Google does something similar with how they re/create ViewModels). If you have time to look over the project linked, it will show all of what I'm doing. I enjoyed the setup while I had it lol. The other parts of the arch package are simply too significant to ignore.

Comment: Ok. Got it. The controller here, I think, takes in data both from the savedInstanceState and the actual Model, and I wonder about how to successfully mix those two things together. I mean, it seems possible that, under some circumstances (like a Screen Reorientation), the controller could get conflicting values from the savedInstanceState bundle vs. the Model. I don't know. Does it just prioritize one data source over the other?

Comment: That's a really good point. Something I never thought of. That conflict is basically the responsibility of the implementation by lack of any actual priority. Considering I am the only one who was using it, that is easy to deal with. Making a single point of data change would improve it, but sort of seems pointless right now.